# An errror while routing in Express.js

Tags: html, node.js, forms, express, routes

I crated a sample shopping cart by Express.js and Node.js. While submittting the form of add-product I got the error as I given in the picture

The url - http://localhost:3000/admin/add-product

the error -
Not Found
404

```
NotFoundError: Not Found
    at C:\Users\aagne\OneDrive\Desktop\ecommerce_dynamic_web\app.js:50:8
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\aagne\OneDrive\Desktop\ecommerce_dynamic_web\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (C:\Users\aagne\OneDrive\Desktop\ecommerce_dynamic_web\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:328:13)
    at C:\Users\aagne\OneDrive\Desktop\ecommerce_dynamic_web\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:286:9
    at Function.process_params (C:\Users\aagne\OneDrive\Desktop\ecommerce_dynamic_web\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:346:12)
    at next (C:\Users\aagne\OneDrive\Desktop\ecommerce_dynamic_web\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:280:10)
    at C:\Users\aagne\OneDrive\Desktop\ecommerce_dynamic_web\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:646:15
    at next (C:\Users\aagne\OneDrive\Desktop\ecommerce_dynamic_web\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:265:14)
    at Function.handle (C:\Users\aagne\OneDrive\Desktop\ecommerce_dynamic_web\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:175:3)
    at router (C:\Users\aagne\OneDrive\Desktop\ecommerce_dynamic_web\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:47:12)
```

This is my app.js

```
var createError = require("http-errors");
var express = require("express");
var path = require("path");
var cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
var logger = require("morgan");

var userRouter = require("./routes/user");
var adminRouter = require("./routes/admin");
var hbs = require("express-handlebars");
var app = express();
var fileUpload = require("express-fileupload");
var db = require("./config/connection");

// view engine setup
app.set("views", path.join(__dirname, "views"));
app.set("view engine", "hbs");

app.engine(
  "hbs",
  hbs.engine({
    extname: "hbs",
    defaultLayout: "layout",
    layoutsDir: __dirname + "/views/layouts/",
    partialsDir: __dirname + "/views/partials/",
    runtimeOptions: {
      allowProtoPropertiesByDefault: true,
      allowProtoMethodsByDefault: true,
    },
  })
);

app.use(logger("dev"));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));
app.use(fileUpload());
db.connect((err) => {
  if(err)
  console.log("Error while connecting Database "+err);
  else
  console.log("Database connected to port 27017");
});

app.use("/", userRouter);
app.use("/admin", adminRouter);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get("env") === "development" ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render("error");
});

module.exports = app;
```

This is my admin.js

```
var express = require("express");
var router = express.Router();

/* GET users listing. */
router.get("/admin", function (req, res, next) {
  let products = [
    {
      name: "Levis Jeans",
      category: "Jeans",
      description: "Levis 501 jeans ",
      image:
        "https://bestmediainfo.com/uploads/2023/03/1678162677.Levis-501R-featuring-Deepika-Padukone.jpg",
    },
    {
      name: "Jacket",
      category: "Jacket",
      description: "LEVIS 501 Jeans Collection",
      image:
        "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSPIv53II1zhL5InjgNuTxHhjC9hurd0Ca1lZGz-1zIbU8_mjRznTr-0BPkTatNFF6IKYw&usqp=CAU",
    },
    {
      name: "Blue Pants",
      category: "Pants",
      description: "Crafted SS23 Collection ",
      image:
        "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRVyhi4e2_7ixiiEao8M9HXoBrQv9KDCjGQsg&usqp=CAU",
    },
    {
      name: "Dark blue Tone",
      category: "Jeans",
      description: "Off 68% for the fall",
      image:
        "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQF97JOLjcmTIDOJM3aUnihD2ww_Mg6CsBXdjOtadiw3djw8xElC6rALs78CWx2rRX-AaA&usqp=CAU",
    },
  ];
  res.render("admin/view-products", { products, admin: true });
});

router.get("/add-product", function (req, res) {
  res.render("admin/add-product");
});

router.post("/add-product", (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  console.log(req.files.Image);
});

module.exports = router;
```

This is my view-product.hbs

```
<section>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row mt-5">
      <a href="/admin/add-product" class="btn btn-success ml-auto">Add Product</a>
    </div>
    <table class="table mt-3">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">No.</th>
          <th scope="col">Name</th>
          <th scope="col">Category</th>
          <th scope="col">Description</th>
          <th scope="col">Image</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {{#each products}}
          <tr>
            <th scope="row">1</th>
            <td>{{this.name}}</td>
            <td>{{this.category}}</td>
            <td>{{this.description}}</td>
            <td><img
                style="width: 60px; height=55px;"
                src="{{this.image}}"
                alt=""
              /></td>
          </tr>
        {{/each}}

      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</section>
```

This is my add-product.hbs

```
<section>
  <div class="container mt-4">
    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-md-6">
        <h2 class="text-center">Add Product</h2>
        <form action="/admin/add-product" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          <label for="">Name</label>
          <input type="text" name="Name" class="form-control" />

          <label for="">Category</label>
          <input type="text" name="Category" class="form-control" />

          <label for="">Price</label>
          <input type="text" name="Price" class="form-control" />

          <label for="">Description</label>
          <input type="text" name="Description" class="form-control" />

          <label for="">Image</label>
          <input type="file" class="form-control" />

          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success mt-4">Submit</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

I tried by changing the name of the router.get() function and the html button click. But still the error exist.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).